# parquet query WHERE clause not working for ARRAY

Tags: hive, hadoop-streaming, parquet

```sql
drop table if exists test_parquet;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_parquet (
ckey string, 
eid string, 
emkey string, 
mkey string,
urid string,
vst array<struct<bd:string, p01:string, p02:string, uid:string, v_h:string, v_w:string, v_m:string,pd:array<struct<c1key:string,cp_met_key:string,od:string,o_key:string,omt:string,sey:string,skey:string>>>>
) 
STORED AS Parquet
LOCATION  '/somelocation';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_parquet SELECT * FROM another_table;
```

Now when I do a

```sql
select * from test_parquet;
```

It works

```sql
select ckey, vst[0].bd, vst[0].pd[0].od from test_parquet limit 10;
```

IT WORKS AS WELL !!

but

```sql
select ckey
from test_parquet 
where test_parquet.vst.p01 in ('A','B','C','D');
```

it FAILS .

Any idea how should an array be written in `where` condition for `parquet` ?

Comment: Think you could post the error you get when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself while working on it . 
select ckey
from test_parquet 
where test_parquet.vst[0].p01 in ('A','B','C','D');
OR 
select ckey
from test_parquet 
where test_parquet.vst[1].p01 in ('A','B','C','D');

This works well because we are trying to access an array and we need to access them via an index.